# Doom Emacs AsciiDoc syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, text, format, ascii

I want to write [AsciiDoc documents](https://asciidoc.org/) in [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (more specifically [Doom Emacs](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs)) with **syntax highlighting**.

I've tried:

- Adding `(package! adoc-mode)` to the bottom of `~/.doom.d/packages.el` .
- Adding `adoc-mode` to `~/.doom.d/init.el`
- Running `~/.emacs.d/bin/doom sync`

But I still get no syntax highlighting.

Syntax highlighting for Markdown and Org-mode do work, not sure if I did something to enable that or if it worked out of the box.

### Edit

Running emacs with the `-Q` or `--quick` option (`emacs -Q`) org-mode has highlighting but markdown does not.

Comment: You can always check if something "works out of the box" by starting with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @NickD With `emacs -Q` org-mode has highlighting but markdown does not.

Comment: Please add all this information to the question (if it is relevant). The question should stand alone and contain all the relevant information, even if the comment is deleted.

Comment: Just for future reference the second step listed is not necessary, only adding it to `packages.el` and running `doom sync` is necessary to get it installed.